# Flutter crashes on launch of app after build. iOS only

Tags: ios, flutter

When I try to launch the ioS emulator, it goes through the process and the icon appears on the screen, the splash screen loads and then crashes.

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.3.4, on macOS 12.5.1 21G83 darwin-x64, locale en-IE)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.6)
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2021.2.2)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.73.1)
[✓] Connected device (4 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability

• No issues found!
```

Flutter doctor comes back fine and I can run the Android emulator.

After hours of trouble shooting I can only think that there is some issue with my iOS folder.

I can go through the whole build process and then then app crashes on launch.
There is no error appearing in the terminal but I'm guessing there is a conflict somewhere.

Could it be the info.plist?

Has anyone got any ideas how I can troubleshot it.

Is there any where I can see a log file or an error?

I have tried emulator and physical device it won't launch past the splash on both

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flutter app doesn't show error logs when the app gets crashed in iPhones, it's common and irritating.

To solve it, by my experience, the protip is:

1. Open its ios folder in Xcode.
2. Select the device in which you want to run it.
3. Run it through Xcode, it will show the errors in Xcode's log panel which you can fix easily then.

Comment: Thanks for your help, that "Protip" worked and I won't forget it. Problem was a Flutter plugin was updated the day before and broke the iOS build but not the android build. The logs would of been the only way of solving it.